# Regular Expression to match '100702' followed by '5' or '6' followed by seven more digits

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regular expression that matches a 15 character string as follows:

- Characters 1-6 should match '100702'
- Characters 7-8 should match '25' or '26'
- Characters 9-15 should match any digit (0-9) but must contain a digit.

This is for .NET

Comment: You should specify the language. Perl has many more special characters than other regex engines, even ones that claim to be Perl-compatible (PCRE). A generic regex is unlikely to work everywhere.

Comment: What flavor of regex? Java? .NET? PHP? Javascript? Something else?

Comment: SO is not a regex generator. What part of the regex are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Thomas - I'm glad not everyone on SO feels as you do. I've got some good answers.

Comment: @Randy: What do you mean by "match any digit (0-9) but must contain a digit." — isn't the 1st condition already include the last one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Characters 9-15 should match any digit (0-9) but must contain a digit" - so there can be other characters than digits there as long as there is at least one digit among them?

Comment: I see two possible interpretation - `[0-9]{7}` and `[0-9]{1,7}`. I assume the first one is the desired one because of the first line of the question: "[...]that matches a 15 character string as follows".

Comment: @Randy Minder: I have answered many similar questions myself, despite feeling that the asker could have taught themselves how to do it. This is a really simple question, and I think you'd be better off learning some basic regex-fu (which really isn't hard for a programmer) than having to turn to SO for all your regex needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one that would work for .NET, following your description:

```
^1007022(5|6)\d{1,7}$
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) reference.

Comment: Characters 9 to 15 are 7 digits... ;) And all 15 digits are always required (as I understand the question).

Answer (score 4):

This is basically what your description says:

```
100702(?:25|26)\d{7}
```

Can also be written:

```
1007022[56]\d{7}
```

You might want to put `^` at the start and `$` at the end if you need to match it entirely  (although certain functions will do this automatically).

Comment: Just a thought - I would always prefer `(25|26)` over `2[56]` or `2(5|6)` because it clearly expresses the requirements. This is always good and especially for our unreadable regular friends.

Comment: I would suggest that you want {1,7} not just {7} at the end there; not sure whether you agree given the ambiguity of "9-15 should match any digit (0-9) but must contain a digit."

Comment: Because of the first line of the question: "[...]that matches a 15 character string as follows" I tend to believe `{7}` is correct.

Comment: Daniel, yes I wrote the (?:25|26) first for that reason - the `?:` tells it not to capture the group (since that was neither asked nor implied necessary). I guess based on the accepted answer that the `{1,7}` range was what was wanted, despite the unclear description.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job.

```
^100702(25|26)[0-9]{7}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article on using a tool to write Regex's http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx and here is a good resource for looking up the matching characters and formats http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm. If you need help after this, please let me know, and I will help you along.